# List of names (hundreds) - easy way to get Salesforce IDs?

Tags: data-loader, tasks, csv

I have a spreadsheet with a list of names - I would like to add an event to all their Salesforce pages using the data loader. It seems like in order to do so I would need their WHOIDs...is there any way to extract this information in an easy format?

If there's a better way to go about this, let me know.

Thanks!

Comment: It's just names, not usernames? Name is not unique so you could have duplicates. Quick & Dirty way is Excel + VLOOKUP.

Comment: @AdrianLarson I have emails too. Could you elaborate a little bit on what you mean by using excel + vlookup? thanks!

Comment: @AdrianLarson thanks for the advice earlier - this ended up being the way to go. I will type up a full answer later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Much delayed but here's how I solved this:

1. Create a contact report in SF with the email and ID fields, export
   to CSV
2. Open the original spreadsheet and the CSV in excel
3. Use VLOOKUP to find the contact SF ID from their email address

Comment: Thanks to Adrian Larson for pointing me in the right direction.